# Running Webpack dev server with custom dev certificates

Tags: webpack, https, openssl, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack dev server and I'd like to use it with https, so I've created a self signed cert following this [guide](https://gist.github.com/pgilad/63ddb94e0691eebd502deee207ff62bd).

For using on the address https://localhost, the default one works just fine. But I've to include the domain name (localhost.myDomain), and then the certificate does not get generate correctly anymore.

And I got:

PEM FILE

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Key file

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I'm running webpack with:

```
"start": "concurrently \"webpack-dev-server --env=dev --open --hot --inline --host localhost.myDomain --https --cert localDev.pem --key localDev.key\" \"dotnet run\" "
```

I've made sure the pem and key file are converted to BOM-8 and that the CR are converted to CRLF, but to no avail. I keep getting this error

```
[1] [11:46:06 INF] [0] Begin compile at 11:46:06 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
[1]
[1] [11:46:06 INF] [0] Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
[1]
[1] [11:46:06 INF] [0]     at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:130:17)
[1] [0]     at Server.setSecureContext (_tls_wrap.js:1155:27)
[1] [0]     at Server (_tls_wrap.js:1033:8)
[1] [0]     at new Server (https.js:65:14)
[1] [0]     at Object.createServer (https.js:89:10)
```

Any idea?

Edit:

I've seen that

```
openssl x509 -text -in localDev.pem
```

returns the expected certificate, but

```
openssl x509 -text -in localDev.key
```

Returns

```
 140427202538824:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

(The right content is returned by  openssl rsa -text -in localDev.key )

Can this be the reason? Is webpack dev server not expecting rsa on the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the webpack-dev-server does not like to have "." in the path (I've some in my project name My.Solution.Project).

I've tried sourcing the pem, key and crt from c:\temp\security and it worked. If I change the directory to c:\temp\security\Users.1 it stops working and gives the mentioned error.

I will copy the files to c:\temp\security as a pre step.